# "Rubber-Safe," or "Rubber Safe?"

Tags: hyphenation

When advertising a product as safe to use on rubber should a hyphen be included between the words "rubber" and "safe?" It seems to me that because it is a compound adjective a hyphen should be used, but analogous usages such as "dishwasher safe" seem to be infrequently hyphenated. Is this one of those situations where the choice is purely preferential?

The product is a chemical compound that will likely be used in environments where rubber is present.

Answer (score 3):

It is evident from various comments and general usage that opinions differ on the necessity of hyphens when a noun is being used as an adjective or adverb. In the absence of violation of any grammatical principles, I therefore suggest one makes ones own judgment on style in these cases.

On what criteria should one make such a judgment? The purpose of writing, whether a literary article, a scientific paper or advertising material, is to communicate ideas, and anything that makes reading more difficult or one’s meaning less clear is an impediment to that communication. I therefore suggest that the criteria one should apply are not popularity or modernity, but *clarity and comprehensibility*.

The general problem here — to which a hyphen can be the solution — is called [false scent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_scent): as one reads a phrase word by word, it is easy to misinterpret the meaning of the word in the phrase, and this is only corrected on reading further, requiring a mental adjustment, slowing comprehension.

The extent of the ambiguity depends on the context in which the pair of words are used, and to some extent on the actual words, so I shall consider some different contexts.
 I shall refer to the combination of the two words (here ‘rubber’ and ‘safe’) as a compound for convenience and to be without prejudice to their parts of speech.

**A. Attributive adjectival use of ‘compound’**

e.g.

> 1. Super Wizzo is a *rubber safe product*

v.

> 2. Super Wizzo is a *rubber-safe product*

Reading 1 up to the first italicized word one can receive an initial impression that either SW is a condom (US) or an eraser (UK). Reading the next word suggests that it is an adjective describing ‘safe’ — a security box — perhaps a safe made of rubber or one for storing condoms or erasers. Only finally is it evident that the two words are a compound adjective describing ‘product’. In 2, the hyphenation of ‘rubber’ and ‘safe’ make it clear that they constitute a compound adjective. It seems to me that the hyphenated form is the obvious choice if one wishes ease of reading.

Even if the initial noun is generally non-countable like rust (e.g. rust + proof) or air (air + tight) then

Super Wizzo is a *rust-proof product*

eliminates the initial puzzlement on encountering ‘a rust’ in

Super Wizzo is a *rust proof product*

Likewise for ‘air-tight’.

**B. Predicative adjectival use of ‘compound’**

For example:

> 1. Super Wizzo is *rubber safe*

v.

> 2. Super Wizzo is *rubber-safe*

Although the compound stands alone, in 1 one can still get false scent from reading the first four words “Super Wizzo is rubber” (made of rubber?) which the hyphen in 2 avoids.

**C. Compound standing alone**

The simplest situation is the compound standing alone, perhaps as labelling on the side of the box of Super Wizzo — *Rubber safe* or  *Rubber-safe*. If the front of the box has a picture of Supper Wizzo and it is clear that it is cleaning product (or whatever) rather than a safe, then the false scent in the form without the hyphen is minimal (especially if it is followed by the inevitable exclamation mark).

Here you can leave out the hyphen if you think it looks cleaner, or stick with it because you’ve come to love hyphens.

**Footnote**

1. Like @MarkHubbard I think “safe to use on rubber” is clearer than “rubber-safe”. But that wasn’t the question, and in advertising words are at a premium.
2. These remarks apply also to “dishwasher-safe”, whether or not it is seldom hyphenated in practice. The ambiguity may be less, but is still present in A and B. One has to apply criteria and make one’s own judgment.

Comment: This was quite helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it's got to be short, I'd suggest **rubber compatible**. 
Rubber safe or rubber-safe is ambiguous imo. Without a hyphen you might have a safe made of rubber or, as the other answerer noted, a safe for rubbers. With or without a hyphen, there's also a possible interpretation that it's safe against the effects of rubber rather than the rubber being safe against its effect; an insect-safe mesh, for instance, is to protect against insects rather than to protect the insects.

In any case I googled "rubber compatible" to see how common it is. It's very common and the first hit was acually a [rubber chemical resistance chart](https://mykin.com/rubber-chemical-resistance-chart). Introduction:

> Here is the *rubber compatibility chart* that rates all popular rubber
>   materials that comes into contact with various chemicals.

Comment: ’Rubber chemical resistance chart‘ is the sort of abomination one reads in scientific journals. Students copy it because it sounds impressive. My doctoral  supervisor purged me of that many years ago. Prepositions can convert it into English: “Chart *of* resistance *of* rubber *to* chemicals”. (If that is what it is intended to mean.)

Comment: Maybe, though I'm not so crazy about that version either with the double 'of'. Anyway the reason I posted was because I prefer 'rubber compatible' to 'rubber safe'. I added the link to show that it can be used in a situation like the one described.

Answer (score 0):

With some educated guess googling, I found a [product bulletin](http://www.nucalgon.com/assets/prodlit/3-84.pdf) for a solvent that is "plastic, metal and rubber safe."  In addition I came across a rubber sealing materials [reference guide](https://www.marcorubber.com/o-ring-material-quick-reference.htm), which includes the descriptive phrase, "Oil and Gas Explosive Decompression Resistant."

For technical publications I like to follow the rule of thumb, "When in Rome, do as the Romans do."

Therefore I recommend

**rubber safe**

<sub>(Given the context there is 0% chance of someone thinking this has the remotest connection to condoms or safes made of rubber.)</sub>